# How to select records where all joined records aren't a match for criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-division

I've a setup with the following tables (using MySQL):

- `orders`, which have many:
- a join table `order_items`, which have one from the:
- `products` table

I've written a query to select `orders` where *all* their `products` are of a certain `type`:

```
SELECT orders.* FROM orders 
INNER JOIN order_items ON order_items.order_id = orders.id   
INNER JOIN products ON products.id = order_items.product_id     
WHERE products.type = 'FooProduct'
AND (
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT null
    FROM products
    INNER JOIN order_items ON order_items.product_id = products.id
    WHERE order_items.order_id = orders.id
    AND products.type != 'FooProduct'
  )
 )
```

I run similar a couple of times: firstly to get orders comprised of all `FooProduct`s, and again to get orders with all `BarProduct`s.

My sticking point has been generating a third query to get all other orders, i.e. where all their products' types are not exclusively `FooProduct`s, or exclusively `BarProduct`s (aka a mix of the two, or other product types).

So, my question is how can I get all records where *all* product types aren't exclusively `FooProduct`s or  exclusively `BarProduct`.

---

Here's a little example data, from which I'd like to return the orders with the IDs 3 and 4:

```
- orders
id
 1
 2
 3
 4

-- order_items

id order_id product_id
 1        1          1
 2        1          1
 3        2          2
 4        2          2
 5        3          3
 6        3          4
 7        4          1
 8        4          2

-- products
id type
 1 'FooProduct'
 2 'BarProduct'
 3 'OtherProduct'
 4 'YetAnotherProduct'
```

I've attempted this, awfully so placing as a subtext, with the following in place of the existing `AND` (even the syntax is way off):

```
NOT HAVING COUNT(order_items.*) = (
  SELECT null
        FROM products
        INNER JOIN order_items ON  order_items.product_id = products.id
        WHERE order_items.order_id = orders.id
        AND products.type IN ('FooProduct', 'BarProduct')
)
```

Comment: You can use conditional aggregation function in `having` clause to filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Correlated subqueries, you can use `Having` and conditional aggregation function based filtering.

`products.type IN ('FooProduct', 'BarProduct')` will return 0 if a product type is none of them. We can use [`Sum()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html) function on it, for further filtering.

Try the following instead:

```
SELECT orders.order_id 
FROM orders 
INNER JOIN order_items ON order_items.order_id = orders.id   
INNER JOIN products ON products.id = order_items.product_id 
GROUP BY orders.order_id 
HAVING SUM(products.type IN ('FooProduct', 'BarProduct')) < COUNT(*)
```

---

For the case, where you are looking for orders which has only `FooProduct` type, you can use the following instead:

```
SELECT orders.order_id 
FROM orders 
INNER JOIN order_items ON order_items.order_id = orders.id   
INNER JOIN products ON products.id = order_items.product_id 
GROUP BY orders.order_id 
HAVING SUM(products.type <> 'FooProduct') = 0
```

Another possible approach is:

```
SELECT orders.order_id 
FROM orders 
INNER JOIN order_items ON order_items.order_id = orders.id   
INNER JOIN products ON products.id = order_items.product_id 
GROUP BY orders.order_id 
HAVING SUM(products.type = 'FooProduct') = COUNT(*)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation and a `having` clause for this:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM orders o INNER JOIN
     order_items oi
     ON oi.order_id = o.id INNER JOIN
     products p
     ON p.id = oi.product_id   
GROUP BY o.id  -- OK assuming `id` is the primary key
HAVING SUM(p.type NOT IN ('FooProduct', 'BarProduct')) > 0;  -- at least one other product
```

Actually, that is not quite right.  This gets orders that have some other product, but it doesn't pick up orders that are mixes only of foo and bar.  I think this gets the others:

```
HAVING SUM(p.type = 'FooProduct') < COUNT(*) AND
       SUM(p.type = 'BarProduct') < COUNT(*)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a relational division problem.
One solution to find orders where **all products are of a given type** is this:

```
SELECT *
FROM orders
INNER JOIN order_items ON order_items.order_id = orders.id
INNER JOIN products ON products.id = order_items.product_id
WHERE orders.id IN (
    SELECT order_items.order_id
    FROM order_items
    INNER JOIN products ON products.id = order_items.product_id
    GROUP BY order_items.order_id
    HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN products.type = 'FooProduct' THEN 1 END) = COUNT(*)
)
```

Tweak the above just a little to find orders where **all products are from a list of given types** is this:

```
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN products.type IN ('FooProduct', 'BarProduct') THEN 1 END) = COUNT(*)
```

And to find all orders where **all products match all types from a given list** is this:

```
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN products.type IN ('FooProduct', 'BarProduct') THEN 1 END) = COUNT(*)
AND    COUNT(DISTINCT products.type) = 2
```

[DB Fiddle with tests](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=674a95e4fe3c9c8f70ca4f32e4c5f413)

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic solution, not so efficient but easy:

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT orders.id FROM orders 
    INNER JOIN order_items ON order_items.order_id = orders.id   
    INNER JOIN products ON products.id = order_items.product_id     
    WHERE products.type = 'FooProduct'
    AND (
      NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT null
        FROM products
        INNER JOIN order_items ON order_items.product_id = products.id
        WHERE order_items.order_id = orders.id
        AND products.type != 'FooProduct'
      )
 )
) AND id NOT IN (
    SELECT orders.id FROM orders 
    INNER JOIN order_items ON order_items.order_id = orders.id   
    INNER JOIN products ON products.id = order_items.product_id     
    WHERE products.type = 'BarProduct'
    AND (
      NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT null
        FROM products
        INNER JOIN order_items ON order_items.product_id = products.id
        WHERE order_items.order_id = orders.id
        AND products.type != 'BarProduct'
      )
 )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using count(distinct) in joined subselect like this:

```
SELECT orders.*
FROM orders 
inner join (
    SELECT orderid, max(products.type) as products_type
    FROM order_items
    INNER JOIN products ON products.id = order_items.product_id
    GROUP BY orderid
    -- distinct count of different products = 1 
    --    -> all order items are for the same product type
    HAVING COUNT(distinct products.type ) = 1 
    -- alternative is:
    -- min(products.type )=max(products.type )
) as tmp on tmp.orderid=orders.orderid 
WHERE 1=1
-- if you want only single type product orders for some specific product
and tmp.products_type = 'FooProduct'
```